# While Loop doesnt break

Tags: python, loops, sockets, cloud-storage

I have been working on making my own cloud storage, but after receiving my file data, it doesn't break the while-loop. It does not proceed to the print statement where it says the file has been downloaded and waits for more data from the server.

Here is the code part where it receives the file data:

```py
if console == "download":
    s.send(bytes("download","utf-8"))

    file_name = input("Enter the file name: ")
    s.send(bytes(file_name,"utf-8"))

    print(f"[DOWNLOADING] Downloading {file_name}")
    
    f = open(file_name,'wb') 

    while(True):
        l = s.recv(1024)
        f.write(l)

        if not l:
            break
    
    print(f"[DOWNLOADED] Downloaded {file_name}")
```

Comment: What exactly is `s`…?

Comment: Have you tried to `print(l)` to see if the if statement should be evaluated as `True`?

Comment: its socket. also if you're wondering if the file is being downloaded, then yes it is being downloaded but it doesnt break the loop.

Comment: Add some logging to see what exactly happens, `recv` is probably blocking, you simply never reach the `break` statement because `l` is never falsey.

Comment: @EliHarold yes i have tried, It stops printing but doesnt break the loop. is there something wrong with the `if not l:` statement. should i use something else? and if so what.

Comment: You most likely need [`socket.socket.settimeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout).

Comment: What makes you assume ``s.recv`` ever returns nothing? Does the other side close the connection once done?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i tried printing out the variable `l`. at some point it does stop printing out the data.

Comment: @Axe319 no the problem is in the `if not l:` statement because socket does stop receiving data. it just doesnt `break`

Comment: That *socket* is *blocking*, waiting for more data. The important part now is: what kind of socket is it exactly and how is it supposed to behave?! Consult its manual how to get it into a non-blocking state. Or tell us more concretely what exactly it is.

Comment: @Shashankh_ Well, "printing out ``l``" will also stop when ``s.recv`` waits for the next ``l`` indefinitely. That does not mean that ``l`` is empty.

Comment: @Shashankh_ If your `print(l)` statement stops printing would that not imply that it isn't being reached? Ask yourself why that would be. Which line would it be stopped on?

Comment: @deceze what do you mean by "what kind of socket"

Comment: There's more than one way to make "a socket". How exactly did you create yours? It's an instance of *what class*? Can you link to a page in the manual that describes it and/or show more informative code?

Comment: @deceze `s = socket.socket()` this is how i defined my socket

Comment: @Axe319 it would be stopped on `if not l:`?

Answer (score 0):

`socket.recv` is a blocking call.

`socket.recv(1024)` will read at most `1024` bytes, blocking if no data is waiting to be read. If you don't read all data, an other call to socket.recv won't block.

socket.recv will also end with an empty string if the connection is closed or there is an error.

If you want a non-blocking socket, you can use the select module (a bit more complicated than just using sockets) or you can use `socket.setblocking`.

Comment: where exactly do i set the `socket.setblocking`

Comment: I will put when you initialize the socket something like: `sock.setblocking(False)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Comment: You can also call recv() as nonblocking if you give the right flag for it: socket.recv(10240, 0x40) # 0x40 = MSG_DONTWAIT a.k.a. O_NONBLOCK Please note that you have to catch the [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable exceptions when there is no input data.

Comment: Hi Jose,
I have tried almost all the solutions but it does not work. please help me with this issue.